# What is the official name "Command Line Tools" or "Xcode Command Line Tools"?

Tags: command-line, xcode, terminology

What is the official name `Command Line Tools` or `Xcode Command Line Tools`?

If you go to https://developer.apple.com/download/all and write *Command Line Tools* as search criteria then in the results appear as *Command Line Tools for **Xcode***, but in the web appears as *Xcode Command Line Tools*.

So what is the official name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Contact Legal

Neither title appears in Apple's non-exhaustive [Trademark List](https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/trademark/appletmlist.html). If you require this information for legal reasons, Apple ask you to [contact their trademark team](https://www.apple.com/legal/contact/#apple-trademark).

### Command Line Tools Package

Apple's [Technical Note TN2339](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) says:

> ## What is the Command Line Tools Package?
>
> The Command Line Tools Package is a small self-contained package available for download separately from Xcode and that allows you to do command line development in macOS. It consists of the macOS SDK and command-line tools such as Clang, which are installed in the `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` directory.